# dnsmasq : answer a default IP if it couldn't be resolved

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I have multiple virtual machines running on Qemu and connected to the internet.
dnsmasq is launched on the host so it can be used :

```
dnsmasq -h --interface=virbr1 --bind-dynamic --dhcp-range=192.168.250.11,192.168.250.253,5m
```

The problem is, sometimes the vms are resolving domain names that are not alive anymore, and I want to redirect that traffic to a honeypot. Is there a way to tell dnsmasq to resolve to a specific IP, all domain names that are not alive anymore?

Comment: How do you define 'not alive any more' ? - are you talking about internal domain names for vm's you've killed off? If so,you need to adjust the 'time to live' the records are being created with.

Comment: I mean public websites which dns do not answer anymore, e.g. "http://lqksjd.com/"